# Refreshing jtree with with thousands of nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am working on a software project that displays a Jtree which may grow up to 20,000 nodes. During the first launch, I have no problem in rendering the nodes, but the problem comes when the nodes has to be refreshed.

I retrieve information and I build node objects under the hood. Now how do I refresh the already displayed Jtree with this newly built nodes.

What would you suggest when we deal with such huge amount of data? I don't want my UI to be frozen when rendering the jtree.

Comment: *"I don't want my UI to be frozen when rendering the jtree."*  Use a `SwingWorker`.  It is made for this type of task.

Comment: Andrew Thompson@ why `SwingWorker`?

Comment: @developerknownasInsane  Did you read as far as the **2nd sentence**  of my comment, or indeed the **1st sentence** of the JavaDocs description of the API?  If those do not make it clear, you'll have to be more specific in your question.

Comment: @developerknownasInsane You have to use `SwingWorker` as long running tasks if run on the `event dispatch thread` would block the UI.

Comment: Extreme Coders@ Thanks i want that an explanations thanks.. :)

Comment: Andrew Thompson@ okay ..!! :)

Comment: @developerknownasInsane  What is with adding `@` as a name suffix?  It totally breaks the notifications mechanism it is designed for.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson okay sorry :p

Comment: @developerknownasInsane  No need for apologies, what people mostly prefer to see is a change.  I see the change (and got notified of that comment).  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson i'll remember next time. :)